# Routes problem with I18n_routing gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, internationalization, routes, translation

I'm on Rails 3 and on my 2nd Rails project (i.e. I'm a newbie). I am making a website with several locales, at the moment Swedish and US. I am using the I18n_routing gem to create localized url:s. I am also using the friendly_id gem to create better urls.

**My problem:** I cannot get my nested urls to be translated. They remain as the default-urls.

This is my routes.rb:

```
  localized(I18n.available_locales, :verbose => true) do
    resources :calculation_types, :only => [:show], :path => '' do
      resources :calculations, :only => [:index, :show], :path => '' do
        member do
          put 'calculate_it'
          get 'calculate_it', :redirect_me => true
          get 'link'
        end
      end
    end  
  end

  localized(I18n.available_locales, :verbose => true) do
    match 'searchresults' => 'home#search-results', :as  => :searchresults
    match 'about' => 'home#about', :as => :about   
    match 'advertise' => 'home#advertise', :as => :advertise
    match 'terms' => 'home#terms', :as => :terms
    match 'calculator' => 'home#calculator', :as => :calculator
    match 'feedback' => 'home#feedback', :as => :feedback
  end
```

This is a sample (cut) of my locale (for Swedish):

```
se:
  named_routes_path:
    about: 'om'
    advertise: 'annonsera'
    calculator: 'kalkylator'
    feedback: 'feedback'
    searchresults: 'sokresultat'  
    terms: 'anvandaranvisning'

  resources: 
    accumulated-passive-income: "vardet-av-din-passiva-inkomst"
    all-about-a-date: "allt-om-ett-datum"
    area: "area"
    average-speed: "genomsnittshastighet"
    birthday-in-days: "fodelsedag-i-dagar"
```

These are some facts of the case:

- The resources-translations include both "calculation_types" and "calculations".
- I have tried several set-ups in the translation file.
- The SECOND routing WORKS, the one with the "match", they also appear when I do rake routes.
- I get no error messages. Everything works fine.
- I am using friendly_id as the url-words. An example of a url could be http://local.domain.com:3000/diet/bmi  where "diet" is calculation_type.friendly_id and bmi is calculation.friendly_id

I want help with:
- Why do the nested routes not show up as routes? Why are they not being created?
- How do I get this to work?

Do you need any more info to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is not a matter of I18n_routing after all since the words that should be translated are actually friendly_id:s. So, disregard the I18n_routing part of this problem and focus on the friendly_id-translation...